# How to apply border class in jQuery for select tag?

Tags: jquery

How to apply border class in jQuery for select tag? Currently I want field using `Select` tag is appearing error. So I do like below. I have no issue with `Input` tag.

[image]

```
<div class="col">
    <select class="form-control" id="selectNE">
        <option value="" selected>-- Select --</option>
    </select>
    <span class='text-danger' id='neError'></span>
</div>

$("#btnSubmit").on("click",function(){
    if ($('#selectNE').val() == ""){
        $('#neError').removeClass('d-none').html("This field is required");
        $('#selectNE').addClass('border border-danger');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show your CSS for those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you have correct CSS class (see below code snippet) and else condition to remove error if select box value is not empty.

BTW, your submit button is missing in the question so you just need to check if there is any console error or if button click event handler is correctly hitting the script.

```js
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function() {
  if ($('#selectNE').val() == "") {
    $('#neError').removeClass('d-none').html("This field is required");
    $('#selectNE').addClass('border border-danger');
  } else {
       $('#neError').addClass('d-none').html("");
      $('#selectNE').removeClass('border border-danger');
  } 
});
```

```css
.border-danger {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <select class="form-control" id="selectNE">
    <option value="" selected>-- Select --</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
  </select>
  <span class='text-danger' id='neError'></span>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Click me">
```